# How can I resolve the "Resource ID #8" error message in PostgreSQL/PHP?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

**How can you solve the *[Resource ID #8](http://www.bigresource.com/PHP-Resource-id-8-CzaOmKEZ.html#)* -error message in the following code?**

The error apparently means that I have a bug in my SQL statement.
However, I cannot see it.

```
 $result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "query1", "SELECT user_id FROM users 
     WHERE email = $1;");
 $result = pg_execute($dbconn, "query1", array("test@gmail.com"));
 // to read the value

 while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
     $user_id = $row[0];
 }
```

I get the error message when I try to `echo $result`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't `echo $result` -- it's a record set, not an actual value to be `echo`ed. You should be able to `echo $row[0]` within the `while` loop, though:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
     $user_id = $row[0];
     echo $user_id . '<br/>';
 }
```

There's nothing wrong with the code that you posted, by the way--the syntax is fine.

Comment: What's the results of this query when run directly against MySQL: `select user_id from users where email = 'test@gmail.com'`

Comment: What if you replace the `pg_execute` with `pg_query()`? Do you get all `user_id`s? If not, you may not be connecting to the database.

Comment: @Eric: I get exactly the same output in connecting to database with pg_query. I can get all `user_id`'s.